# Boostrap glyphicon checkbox, jquery to check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

Thanks in advance. I'm so close to getting a label to check a checkbox, using css, boostrap and javascript. The problem is that when *clicked THE FIRST TIME*, the jquery works but the css doesn't. ONLY after the first time does it work.

html

```
   <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="glyphicon"></span>
    </label>
```

css

```
label.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]  {
  display:none;
}

label.checkbox span  {
  margin:-4px auto;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid #BBB;
  border-radius:100px;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background:#f33;
  position: relative;
  transition:background 0.4s;
}

label.checkbox span:before,
label.checkbox :checked + span:after  {
  position:absolute;
  font-size:100px;
  top: 8px;
  left:8px;
}

label.checkbox span:before  {
  content: "\e088";
  color:#333;
}

label.checkbox :checked + span:before  {
  visiblity:hidden;

}
label.checkbox span:after  {
  content:'';
}
label.checkbox :checked + span {
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background:#3f3;
}
label.checkbox :checked + span:after {
  content: '\e089';
  color: #333;
}
```

jquery

```
//if checkbox becomes checked
  $('label span').on('click', function() {
    check = $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox');
//is checked true = uncheck, false = check
   (check.prop('checked') ? check.attr('checked', false) : check.attr('checked', true));
  });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9L91zmd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the first time, when you click on the label the value of the checkbox is set false so per your ternary operator, it doesn't show changes.

You need to do like this to see changes

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   ($(this).is(":checked") ? $(this).attr('checked', true) :     $(this).attr('checked', false));
   });
});
```

Here you can see the effect [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sumn2u/nyoa4tyc/1/)

Comment: Thanks that fixes the first click change, but if you inspect the checkbox to for the change to 'checked' it still only happens on second action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript

```
    $('label span').on('click', function() {

    check = $(this).prev().find('input:checkbox');
//is checked true = uncheck, false = check
    (check.prop('checked') ? check.attr('checked', false) : check.attr('checked', true));
  });
```

Comment: That fixes the first click for the change, but it doesn't add 'checked' to the checkbox until multiple actions, when you inspect the element.